# Twilio Extension: "The selected contacts have no valid phone, or prefer not to receive SMS, or are deceased."

Tags: sms

I am on Drupal 7.51 / CiviCRM 4.7.12

I have just installed Twilio (SMS) Extension, purchased a number (+33... (France) from Twilio), upgraded my account, and configured Twilio Extension accordingly (as per https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Setting+up+a+SMS+Provider+for+CiviSMS) : filling username and password with the LIVE API Credentials specified at https://www.twilio.com/console/account/settings.

When I test it (on a test Group), I get the following Error Message :

The selected contacts have no valid phone, or prefer not to receive SMS, or are deceased.

(I did not configure inbound SMS)

Any suggestion would be welcome

Comment: Just to be complete, the phone must be of the type _Mobile_. Did you succeed sending a single SMS?

Comment: Thank you Kainuk for your attention ; of course, the phone called is mobile.  When I select and consult an individual, the SMS action is not available in the action list ; when I select (tag) an individual in a search result and send him a SMS, I get the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot, Kainuk for your screenshots : the error is on my side : I thought that just the number had to be a mobile number : I did not realize that, moreover, this number had to be defined as a Home **Mobile** phone number.

I have now to change that in my webforms (and then fix this in all the database, but I can manage this directly with phpmyadmin).

Thanks again a lot : I would not have found that by myself.

Comment: The devil is in the details :-). Glad it works now.

Answer (score 1):

Just the start of debugging, but maybe it evolves to a complete answer. I focus on the fact that the Send SMS menu does not show on a contact with a valid mobile phone. Can you execute the following script with your test contact_id (my test contact id = 204)?

```
<pre>
<?php
  $testContactId = 204;
  civicrm_initialize();
  if(CRM_SMS_BAO_Provider::activeProviderCount()){
     echo "SMS provider configured\n";
     $mobileTypeID = CRM_Core_OptionGroup::getValue('phone_type', 'Mobile', 'name');
     echo "Mobile type id =  $mobileTypeID \n";
       print_r(CRM_Contact_BAO_Contact_Location::getPhoneDetails($testContactId, $mobileTypeID));
  } else {
     echo "NO Sms provider configured\n";
 };
?>
</pre>
```

To execute the script save it to a file (for example *test.php*) and run it with

```
drush scr test.php
```

Hopefully, we get a hint if the configuration of the provider is the problem or the details of the test contact.

*Update*
When you have only web access the code can be executed on a Drupal instance as follows:

- Enable the Drupal **PHP Filter** module.
- Create a new Article
- Past the script as contents of the article
- Set the filter to **PHP Code**
- Use the preview button for the result.

A word of warning, enabling the PHP Filter is a security risk because it allows the execution of arbitrary PHP code in every Drupal page.

Comment: Thanks again Kainuk. Unfortunately I am not a programmer, but I can manage that with FTP : Where should I store this file ? Can I call it via a URL (instead of drush, which I am not familiar with) ? (If not, just tell me how to use this drush command). PS : sorry for this answer delay, but I am located in France

Comment: Hi Jacques, updated the answer, with an alternative solution to execute the script. But on my test instance, I have the send SMS send menu working, so I will create a second answer, where I show them. (By the way, I am in Culemborg, the Netherlands, so we are in the same timezone).

Answer (score 0):

I got the *send SMS* working on my test instance. I post here the screenshots. Maybe it will be of help if you compare?

1. The objective is to show the *Send SMS* menu. That makes it possible to send a single SMS for testing purposes.
2. The test contact must have a phone number of the type mobile, and it must be the *Primary*.
3. No privacy option is set.

[image: screenshot of an enable SMS contact]

This is the configuration of my SMS provider screen. API parameters have no effect, but the checkbox *Is this provider active?* (2) does!.

[image]