# CiviCRM Twilio extension working for mass SMS but not individual SMS

Tags: civisms

I have civicrm 4.7.22 running on wordpress 4.8.1.  The Twilio extension works well for sending mass SMS with no errors.  However the option to "Send SMS" does not appear anywhere in the Actions menu on a contact or the Activities tab.  Is there something else I need to do to enable individual SMS?

[image: Screenshot of contact activities list]

Comment: Is the primary phone number of your test contact of the type Mobile. The extension uses this to show the action. For more information see the discussion on https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/16184/twilio-extension-the-selected-contacts-have-no-valid-phone-or-prefer-not-to-r/16193#16193 .

Comment: @Kainuk-CiviCooP Yes the primary number of the test contact is of type Mobile.  And anyway a mass SMS works and an activity is created on the test contact showing the mass SMS is sent and received.   I ran the code on the linked page and got: SMS provider configured Mobile type id = 2 Array ( [0] => [name redacted] [1] => [mobile number redacted] [2] => 0 )

Comment: Okay, that proves that your test contact is correct.